# Run specific action based on which viewcontroller is being shown/loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a few different `UIViewController`'s and `UITableViewController`'s being accessed from one view, i.e. the root location of the app. To make everything look nice, I've done a few things like make the removing of the nav bar animated, and setting a delay on the status bar when it changes from light content to default, to give time for the nav bar to disappear (just makes it look better, and the status bar is then readable at any time)

Anyway, I'm wondering if there's any way to change what happens in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidDisappear`, etc. based on which view is about to be shown/loaded? So when going to view1, we do transition1, and when going to view2, we do transition2.

I'm thinking this will involve else if statements, but what gets put there to determine which view is which, I'm unsure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom View Controller transitioning knows which controllers are being transitioned form, and to.

You can set your viewController's transitioning delegate, like so:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ....   
    UIViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    detailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
}
```

Implement the necessary delegate methods, specifying whichever transition applies for the view you'll be presenting/dismissing:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                  presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                      sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {

   YourTransitionAnimator1 *animator = [YourTransitionAnimator1 new];
   animator.presenting = YES;
   return animator;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
   YourTransitionAnimator1 *animator = [YourTransitionAnimator1 new];
   return animator;
}
```

That's where you add the necessary conditional code, to determine whether your animation will be transition1 or transition2.

This is covered in [WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/) Session 218, Custom Transitions Using View Controllers.